# how to get pinned row data in AG-grid angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using ag-grid-angular in my angular application and pinned a row in the table. I want to get the values in the pinned row. How to do it?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the ag-grid [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-pinning/), we can pin rows either on the top, or the bottom of the grid.

Therefore, we can actually get the values of the pinned rows by using the in-built grid api by using `gridApi.getPinnedTopRow(index)` or `gridApi.getPinnedBottomRow(index)`. Assuming you want to get the first   top/bottom pinned row on the grid, you can do this:

```
console.log(this.gridApi.getPinnedTopRow(0).data);
console.log(this.gridApi.getPinnedBottomRow(0).data);
```

Comment: what a bad implementation, why they dont have a getPinnedTopRowData function to get all of them, the same way you set them...